was の not used to nominalize in old speech?
This is a line from a character who uses old speech:
「死戦をくぐるは、我が享楽！」
Was の not used for nominalization in old speech, or is it missing after the は (an error)? I'm not very familiar with archaic Japanese.

no as nominalizer seems to be attested since 17th century, which is early Modern Japanese.
Bjarke Frellesvig (2010, "A History of the Japanese Language", page 364):

However, in early NJ no emerged as a nominalizer which came to be used in these functions. (38) contains two early examples:
(38) a.
[soregasi ga  suite    yomu]       no   wa  seisuiki o   suite    yomu
 I        NOM like.GER read.NONPST NMLZ TOP Seisuiki ACC like.GER read.NONPST
'What I like reading is (I like reading) the (Genpei) Seisuiki' (Kyōgen-ki, c. 1660)
b.
[fara   no  tatu]       no   wa  warui
stomach GEN rise.NONPST NMLZ TOP bad.NONPST
'It is bad that he is angry' (Kabuki jūhachibanshū, c. 1700)


Some other methods of nominalization of verbs:

Suffix -aku (where /a/ is sometimes elided, or fused with preceding /i/ to form e1 which was possibly /je/)
This suffix was productive in Old Japanese (700 - 800), but became fossilized in first part of Early Middle Japanese (800 - 1200). Its traces remain in words such as iwaku (曰く) ← ipaku ← ip- + -aku.
2 forms of nominalization for Old Japanese Simple Past tense suffix -ki:
-ki + -aku → kyeku
-si + -aku → siku
For all vowel-stem verbs, regular and irregular, this suffix was attached to Attributive (連体形{れんたいけい}) form, and is therefore hypothesized to come from earlier noun *aku ("thing, place").
mi- + -uru + -aku → miraku ("seeing")
se- + -uru + -aku → suraku ("doing")

Suffix -i (homophonous with Continuative (連用形{れんようけい}) except possibly different pitch accent)
This method is productive for construction VERB + -i  ni  iku/kuru ("to go to do something"), but otherwise is not very productive and then has very varying meanings, as explained here.

Attributive (連体形{れんたいけい}) used as noun
This method is archaic in modern Japanese, and is seen in your example sentence in this question.

Separate nouns such as koto and mono



"(38) contains two early examples:" - I assume this "suite" is 好く in te-form? Was that common in this era? Seems like the verb entirely disappeared outside of using 好き as a na-adjective.

@KarlKnechtel Yes, it is 好く. Gloss says like.GER, where GER = gerund. I do not know when verb 好く started to fall into disuse. See also this.
